# How can I install fzf in vim without using a plugin manager?

Tags: gvim, plugin-system, plugin

I have fzf installed in manjaro (`/usr/bin/fzf`, `/usr/share/fzf`), but I can't seems to figure out how to install fzf for vim. I'm having trouble following these instructions: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md.

Note:
This is just for completion; actually with `:LogiPat` search, what I needed is achievable already.

Comment: @kadekai I don't use any vim-plug.. i just drop plugin into a default folder.  
~/.vim/pack/My_plugins/start
example plugins currently i have are: 
minimap-vim  nerdtree  temp_bak  vim-visual-star-search

Comment: @kadekai I know https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim . After having read it, i can't understand how to install it, that's the problem.

Comment: @andrew_ysk. For fzf, you need two plugins in `~/.vim/myplugs/start/`  https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim.git and https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), and here are the
relevant lines in my .vimrc to install
[fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim):

```
" If installed using git
set runtimepath+=~/.fzf

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim 
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required 
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' } 
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end() " required
```

And here's a bit of configuration (just how I personally like it):

```
" when I search for a file, show results in a window at the bottom
let g:fzf_layout = { 'down': '~40%' }

" remove the config for preview window (I prefer vim's default behaviour)
let fzf1 = "--height 80% -m --layout=reverse --marker=o"
let fzf2 = ""
let fzf3 = "--bind ctrl-a:select-all,ctrl-d:deselect-all"
let fzf4 = "--bind ctrl-y:preview-up,ctrl-e:preview-down"
let $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS = fzf1.' '.fzf2.' '.fzf3.' '.fzf4
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I would like to know If i can go with the default method without plugin manager (. ~/.vim/pack/My_plugins/start   ), why should i go with plugin manager ? which only bulk down vim.

Comment: @andrew_ysk ah, then I'm not sure how to do it without the plugin manager, sorry.

Comment: Oh, i just dropped in UndoTree into  ~/.vim/pack/My_plugins/start  this folder location and restart vim.. it just run. no need extra manager.